# Como compilar C++ no VisualStudio usando o linux dentro do windows

Tags: c++, linux

Um amigo falou que tem como fazer esta compilação pelo VisualStudio e rodar em um "subsistema" linux

Comment: Nunca fiz, pode usar o WSL https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10. Na verdade gerar o executável para o Linux já pode sem ele. Ele é necessário para testar sua aplicação no Linux estando no Windows. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/02/08/targeting-windows-subsystem-for-linux-from-visual-studio/ e https://www.hanselman.com/blog/WritingAndDebuggingLinuxCApplicationsFromVisualStudioUsingTheWindowsSubsystemForLinux.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Este [tutorial da Microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/30/visual-c-for-linux-development/) exemplifica como fazer isso no visual studio, porém para executar segundo o tutorial você vai precisar de uma máquina com linux conectada remotamente (Não tenho certeza se seria possível utilizar uma máquina virtual), aparentemente o mesmo procedimento serve para o raspbery pi ou qualquer outra variação do linux.